# How to Run LWUIT RssReader Example App in j2me

Tags: java-me, lwuit

i found one example App for creating Rss Reader using lwuit,the example app url is

"https://projects.developer.nokia.com/LWUIT_for_Series_40/browser/IO/src/com/sun/lwuit/io/ui/RSSReader.java"

i have gone through the code ,but in this Example there is no Midlet creation and somme of the classess below classes are not found in lwuit  jar file

```
     import com.sun.lwuit.io.NetworkEvent;
    import com.sun.lwuit.io.NetworkManager;
    importcom.sun.lwuit.io.services.RSSService;
    import com.sun.lwuit.layouts.BoxLayout;
    import com.sun.lwuit.list.DefaultListModel;
```

Can any one guide me to execute this example app successfully on my device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain all `com.sun.lwuit` source code from an svn checkout. Url https://svn.java.net/svn/lwuit~svn Take a look at LWUIT_1_5 root folder.

Comment: in LWUIT_1_5  root folder ,where can i find the Required Source Code?I have gone through the LWUIT_1_5 root folder?

Comment: com.sun.lwuit.io is found at IO/src folder. com.sun.lwuit.layouts and com.sun.lwuit.list is found at UI/src.

Answer (score 1):

I also went through this problem. For the lwuit.jar you can go two ways: (1) download the source code of the subversion repository (response by Telmo) and compile the files in NetBeans IDE; or (2) get a version of LWUIT already compiled by someone.

To open source code with NetBeans go:
NetBeans IDE menu / Team / Subversion / Checkout /

Access the source code using the following URL:

https://svn.java.net/svn/lwuit~svn (anonymous)

or SSH URL (requires SSH key): svn+ssh://@svn.java.net/lwuit~svn

After import all projects (like UI, IO... and build it). (required WTK 2.5.2 reference - in project property), can use the new libs in their examples.